PCIe driver, Bus Mastering DMA and dma_alloc_coherent
I a trying to write a linux-driver for a PCIe device which should have bus mastering capabilities. I am encountering the problem that the buffer space, when initialized with dma_alloc_coherent() is not reachable by a user-space application. A function says more than a thousand words, so I will post the most important pieces of code :

    //Private driver structure
    struct pcichardev {
        struct bar_t bar;
        dev_t major;
        struct cdev cdev;
        void * buffer;
        dma_addr_t buffer_phys;
    };



    static int pci_probe(struct pci_dev *pdev, const struct pci_device_id *id){

        printk("Entering pci-probe\n");

        int errno = 0;
        int num_mem_bars;
        struct pcichardev *locpcichar;
        struct device *dev;
        dev_t dev_num;

        locpcichar = kmalloc(sizeof(struct pcichardev), GFP_KERNEL); //should be right choice

        if(!locpcichar){
            errno = -ENOMEM;
            goto failure_kmalloc;
        }


        errno = pci_enable_device_mem(pdev);
        if(errno){
            goto failure_pci_enable;
        }

        pci_set_master(pdev); //enable bus mastering

        // enable 64 bit DMA
        dma_set_mask_and_coherent(&(pdev->dev), DMA_BIT_MASK(64));

        //allocate memory for bus mastring operations
        void *buffer;
        dma_addr_t buffer_handle;
        size_t buffer_size = 4096; // Allocate a 4KB buffer, adjust size as needed

        // Allocate DMA-coherent memory for bus-mastering transfers
        buffer = dma_alloc_coherent(&(pdev->dev), buffer_size, &buffer_handle, GFP_USER);
        if (!buffer) {
            dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Failed to allocate DMA memory\n");
            return -ENOMEM;
        }

        printk("address of buffer is %p\n", (void *) buffer);
        printk("buffer handle is : %llx\n", buffer_handle);

        locpcichar->buffer = buffer;
        locpcichar->buffer_phys = buffer_handle;

        printk("DMA buffer allocated at virtual address: %p, physical address: 0x%llx, handle is : 0x%llx\n", buffer, virt_to_phys(buffer), buffer_handle);

        //request only the bars containing a memory region
        num_mem_bars = pci_select_bars(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM);
        errno = pci_request_selected_regions(pdev, num_mem_bars, "pci-char");
        if(errno){
            goto failure_pci_regions;
        }

        //Memory map BARs to MMIO regions
        if(num_mem_bars){
            locpcichar->bar.addr = ioremap(pci_resource_start(pdev,0), pci_resource_len(pdev, 0));
            if(IS_ERR(locpcichar->bar.addr)){
                errno = PTR_ERR(locpcichar->bar.addr);
            }else{
                locpcichar->bar.len = pci_resource_len(pdev, 0);
            }
        }else{
            locpcichar->bar.addr = NULL;
            locpcichar->bar.len = 0;
        }

        //if there was an error, then perform unmapping
        if(errno){
            if(locpcichar->bar.len){
                iounmap(locpcichar->bar.addr);
            }
            goto failure_ioremap;
        }
        //get the minor number range of the device, for now, it should all be zero
        errno = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev_num, 0, 1, "xpci_chrdev");
        if(errno){
            goto failure_alloc_chrdev_region;
        }

        locpcichar->major = MAJOR(dev_num);

        //connect this chrdev instance with all previously defined character operations
        cdev_init(&locpcichar->cdev, &fops);
        locpcichar->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;

        //add cdev with major/min number, quite useless, as we only have a BAR, and thus a minor number
        errno = cdev_add(&locpcichar->cdev, MKDEV(locpcichar->major, 0), 1);
        if(errno){
            goto failure_cdev_add;
        }


        //create /dev nodes with udev
        if(locpcichar->bar.len){
            dev = device_create(pchar_class, &pdev->dev,
                                MKDEV(locpcichar->major, 0),
                                NULL, "b%xd%xf%x_bar%d",
                                pdev->bus->number,
                                PCI_SLOT(pdev->devfn),
                                PCI_FUNC(pdev->devfn), 0);
            if(IS_ERR(dev)){
                errno = PTR_ERR(dev);
            }
        }

        printk("PCI-PROBE : Bar at address %p, with length : %ld \n", (void *) locpcichar->bar.addr, (unsigned long) locpcichar->bar.len);

        if(errno){
            if(locpcichar->bar.len){
                device_destroy(pchar_class, MKDEV(locpcichar->major, 0));
            }
            goto failure_device_create;
        }

        pci_set_drvdata(pdev, locpcichar);
        dev_info(&pdev->dev, "claimed by xpci_chrdev\n");

        return 0;

        failure_device_create:
            printk("failure device create\n");
            cdev_del(&locpcichar->cdev);

        failure_cdev_add:
            printk("failure cdev add\n");
            unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(locpcichar->major, 0), 1);

        failure_alloc_chrdev_region:
            printk("failure alloc cdev region\n");
            if (locpcichar->bar.len)
                iounmap(locpcichar->bar.addr);

        failure_ioremap:
            printk("failure ioremap\n");
            pci_release_selected_regions(pdev, pci_select_bars(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM));

        failure_pci_regions:
            printk("failure pci regions\n");
            pci_disable_device(pdev);

        failure_pci_enable:
            printk("failure pci enable\n");
            kfree(locpcichar);

        failure_pci_mastering:
            printk("failure in setting pci dev to bus-mastering\n");
            kfree(locpcichar);

        failure_kmalloc:
            printk("failure kmalloc\n");
            return errno;

    }

static int xdev_mmap(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma) {

    vma->vm_flags |= VM_DONTCOPY | VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_NORESERVE | VM_DONTDUMP | VM_PFNMAP;
    //vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);

    struct pcichardev *locpcichar = file->private_data;

    printk("In mmap\n");

    printk("vma size : %d\n", vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start);
    printk("buffer_phys @ 0x%llx", locpcichar->buffer_phys);
    printk("virt_to_phys delivers 0x%llx", virt_to_phys(locpcichar->buffer_phys));

    // Map the DMA-coherent memory to user-space
    int ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
                              locpcichar->buffer_phys >> PAGE_SHIFT,
                              vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,
                              vma->vm_page_prot);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("Failed to mmap DMA buffer to user-space\n");
        return -EIO;
    }

    return 0;
}

so much for the driver, what I am trying to do in the user-space application is the following :
// Step 1: Open the character device
    fd = open(DEVICE_PATH, O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open the device");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Step 2: Map the DMA buffer to user-space
    dma_buffer = mmap(NULL, BUFFER_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    printf("MMAP delivered the following address : %p\n", dma_buffer);

    if (dma_buffer == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Failed to mmap the device");
        close(fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Step 3: Initialize the buffer with test data
    data = (uint32_t *) dma_buffer;
    for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE / sizeof(uint32_t); i++) {
        data[i] = i;
    }

    // Step 4: Verify data in the DMA buffer after the transfer
    printf("Verifying data in the DMA buffer...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE / sizeof(uint32_t); i++) {
        printf("data at pos %i --> 0x%x\n",i, data[i] );
        if (data[i] != i) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Data mismatch at index %d: expected 0x%X, got 0x%X\n", i, i, data[i]);
        }
    }

Incredibly enough making the following changes actually makes the application work :
static int xdev_mmap(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma) {

    vma->vm_flags |= VM_DONTCOPY | VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_NORESERVE | VM_DONTDUMP | VM_PFNMAP;
    //vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);

    struct pcichardev *locpcichar = file->private_data;

    printk("In mmap\n");

    printk("vma size : %d\n", vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start);
    printk("buffer_phys @ 0x%llx", locpcichar->buffer_phys);
    printk("virt_to_phys delivers 0x%llx", virt_to_phys(locpcichar->buffer_phys));

    // Map the DMA-coherent memory to user-space
    int ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
                              virt_to_phys(locpcichar->buffer) >> PAGE_SHIFT,
                              vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,
                              vma->vm_page_prot);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("Failed to mmap DMA buffer to user-space\n");
        return -EIO;
    }

    return 0;
}

int errno = 0;
    int num_mem_bars;
    struct pcichardev *locpcichar;
    struct device *dev;
    dev_t dev_num;

    locpcichar = kmalloc(sizeof(struct pcichardev), GFP_KERNEL); //should be right choice

    if(!locpcichar){
        errno = -ENOMEM;
        goto failure_kmalloc;
    }

    errno = pci_enable_device_mem(pdev);
    if(errno){
        goto failure_pci_enable;
    }

    pci_set_master(pdev); //enable bus mastering

    // enable 64 bit DMA
    dma_set_mask_and_coherent(&(pdev->dev), DMA_BIT_MASK(64));

    //allocate memory for bus mastring operations
    void *buffer;
    dma_addr_t buffer_handle;
    size_t buffer_size = 4096; // Allocate a 4KB buffer, adjust size as needed

    buffer = kmalloc(buffer_size, GFP_USER);
    if (!buffer) {
        dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Failed to allocate DMA memory\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    printk("address of buffer is %p\n", (void *) buffer);
    printk("buffer handle is : %llx\n", buffer_handle);

    buffer_handle = dma_map_single(&pdev->dev, buffer, buffer_size, DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL);

    locpcichar->buffer = buffer;
    locpcichar->buffer_phys = buffer_handle;

    printk("DMA buffer allocated at virtual address: %p, physical address: 0x%llx, handle is : 0x%llx\n", buffer, virt_to_phys(buffer), buffer_handle);


What am I doing wrong here? sorry for the dumb question...
EDIT : Thanks a lot for the comments, it turns out I was using buffer_handle in the wrong way. This neveretheless opened the way to a new problem. I will post the functions to illustrate what I mean :
The driver structure remains unchanged, with :
//Private driver structure
struct pcichardev {
    struct bar_t bar;
    dev_t major;
    struct cdev cdev;
    void * buffer;
    dma_addr_t buffer_phys;
};

when allocating a buffer with kmalloc and then using remap_pfn_range, all is working as I posted before. Using dma_alloc_coherent things start to be compliacted. According to Some questions on dma_alloc_coherent I should just do the following, after dma_alloc_coherent :
vma->vm_flags |= VM_DONTCOPY | VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_NORESERVE | VM_DONTDUMP | VM_PFNMAP;     
vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);//added last flags
vma->vm_pgoff = virt_to_phys(locpcichar->buffer)>>PAGE_SHIFT;

remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, //no io
                        vma->vm_pgoff,
                        vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,
                        vma->vm_page_prot);

I then mmap the range from the user application, and have modified my ioctl call, as to actually print the data in the buffer from the kernel. I can see the data from userspace and kernel, via mmap and ioctl, when using the kmalloc+dma_map_single trick, but when using dma_alloc_coherent I can only see the data, written to the memory range wia write() from kernel space. mmap does not seem to have any effect, as from the userspace I am getting back the IOMMU dummy-data (0xFFFF_FFFF) and from the kernel-space I am getting 0x0000_0000 (which should be right since I never wrote to it).
Maybe something worth being said is that this is a very weird setup. I am using the PCIe component of an FPGA as a loopback element, to write to the memory allocated on the host. Writing/reading works with write/read character device operations, just mmap does now when using dma_alloc_coherent.
Here is a picture of what I am trying to do :

I am very puzzled by this, anyway I have managed to find similar error, from 2012, here : Linux PCI Driver, mmap prefetching; these options do nevertheless seem to be outdated.
Well you may ask, how can you be sure that your FPGA-mumbo-jumbo is working ? Legitimate question, but well, if read/write works, and the data is landing in the memory region on the host system, as well as mmap under some circumnstances, then I am sure that the FPGA stuff is working 100%. There are some address conversions going on there, but that has been validated.
I am sorry if I am a dumbfuck, but really I ran out of bunnies to pull out of my cylinder here...
I am using 6.1.0-25-amd64
PS: I know that the offset on the bus is 0xFFFF_F000, both dma_alloc_coherent and dma_map_single give me back that when allocating a page (4096 Bytes), quite unorthodox solution, but it works.
PS.1 : I get the same behaviour when using dma_mmap_coherent.
PS.2 : Yes, I can write to locpcichar->buffer, allocated from dma_alloc_coherent from the kernel space

In your original code you seem use DMA address, filled with dma_alloc_coherent, as physical address (buffer_phys field). Linux kernel Documentation tells this is not a correct usage: "A CPU cannot reference a dma_addr_t directly because there may be translation between its physical address space and the DMA address space."

+1 to what @Tsyvarev said. virt_to_phys() is not for DMA bus addresses. Every now and then someone fails on the same, I used to commented a post per 3 months a few years ago, so a new wave seems coming :)

@Tsyvarev, thanks for pointing it out. It was the mistake all along, I completely ignored the second sentence in the Linux Kernel Documentation.

You can call dma_mmap_coherent to mmap DMA coherent memory.
